# asp.net textbox array with events

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, textbox

### I have the following code in the page source:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

### And in code behind page:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles     Button1.Click        
For i As Integer = 0 To 9            
Dim box As New TextBox()            
box.ID = "textBox" + CStr(i)            
box.Width = 20            
box.Text = CStr(i)            
box.TabIndex = CShort(i + 1)            
AddHandler box.TextChanged, AddressOf ClickBox
panel1.Controls.Add(box)        
Next    
End Sub    

Private Sub ClickBox(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)        
Dim boxUsed = DirectCast(sender, TextBox)        
boxUsed.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Crimson        
End Sub
```

---

The problem is TextChange event for texboxes doesn't fire.

Answer (score 0):

Two things. First:

```
box.AutoPostBack = True
```

Second:
Since you're creating textboxes dynamically, they will be gone between every postback, unless you re-create them in the Page_Load event.